# How to use Jest with Webpack

Tags: webpack, jestjs

Is it possible to use Jest with Web pack? I mean using it in parallel with Web pack hot-load.And Run our tests every time when Web pack will build the project .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my goals I use [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) with this package I am able to run two process for watch files and run tests.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will work out of the box using [babel-jest](https://github.com/babel/babel-jest). Have a look at the [tutorial](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-webpack.html#content) from the jest docs.

Comment: I know that it works out of the box. But I can't find how to start test every time when web pack build the project.

Comment: You mean on every file change? Use `jest --watch` in this case.

Comment: Yeah, But I want to use it at the same time with web-pack. When I add changes I use or webpack hot reload or jest --watch.

Comment: I don't get the problem. When something changed webpack-dev-server will rebuild the app and jest runs the test. I you mean building the app for  production you can use a npm script like this:  `"build": jest && webpack ./scr ./build`

Comment: When I run web pack it just builds my project. If I want to run the tests I must write "npm run jest". But I don't understand how to do it just using web pack. For example, I write to console 'web pack' and after that, it runs tests and builds the project.